# C memory allocation with File input

Tags: c, memory, malloc, calloc

Hello i have a problem with memory allocation,

  1. open file

  2. take lenght of text inside

  3. make buffer in size of lenght (array[] ? malloc ?)

  4. make operations on text in buffer.

  5. close

it terminates when text any longer than 1xx characters i have no idea whats going on.

**ps**.attention! im learning and quality of this code can be bad

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void copy_to_buffer(FILE *fp, int length, char *buffer){
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        char c = fgetc(fp);
        buffer[i] = c;
    }
}
int length_of_text(FILE *fp) {
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    return size;
}

void char_counter(int length, char *buffer, int *charBuffer) {
    int counts[128] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        counts[(int)(buffer[i])]++;
        charBuffer[i] = counts[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        charBuffer[i] = counts[i];
        if(counts[i] != 0)
            printf("%d.(%c) counted: %d times.\n", i,i, counts[i]);
    }
}
/***********************************MAIN***********************************/
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    FILE *fp = fopen("tekst.txt" , "r");
    int length = length_of_text(fp);                //lenght of text
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*length);     //buffer for text from file
    if(buffer == NULL) 
        printf("error");
    else
        printf("alocated at = %p\n", &buffer);

    int charBuffer[128] = {0}; // charcount buffer
    buffer[length] = '\0';   // '\0' after last sign
    copy_to_buffer(fp, length, buffer); 
    char_counter(length, buffer, charBuffer); 

    free(buffer);
    fclose(fp);     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: `printf("alocated at = %p\n", &buffer);` --> `printf("alocated at = %p\n", (void*)buffer);`

Comment: One of the problems lies on this line - `counts [ (int)(buffer[i]) ]++` When you cast char to an int it gives you the ascii representation , not the actual char that you see being converted to a number.

Comment: `buffer[length] = '\0';` out of bounds.

Comment: Is `tekst.txt` 7bit code?

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer: I would guess that's the purpose of this program. (I foresee huge problems when the text file contains characters outside the plain ASCII range. Maybe that is not an issue, but then again it may be.)

Comment: yes tekst.txt is ascii 7bit

Comment: delete first `charBuffer[i] = counts[i];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `char_counter` function you do

```
charBuffer[i] = counts[i];
```

in the first for loop but buffer is only defined to be 128 ints. If  the text is longer than 128 characters this will cause a buffer overflow and a segmentation fault.

Remove that line and let the 2nd for loop do it.

Comment: my fault i didnt saw that

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
charBuffer[i] = counts[i];
```

you will overflow `charBuffer[128]` when the file size is >= 128, since `i` is indexing by up to the length of the file.